# qt designer how to select multiple children of a QStackedWidget page?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

In qt designer, I have placed a QStackedWidget with 2 pages inside QMainWindow. And there are many widgets inside the first page as shown below:
[image]

**Now, I want to select all widgets inside the red box area. How to do that easily?**

It seems I can not select multiple widgets by selecting a rectangle area with my mouse.

**Update:
I know I can press CTRL and click all widgets I want one by one. But it seems time consuming when there are hundreds of widgets which is possible in my app.**

Comment: You can select many widgets by pressing the key ```ctrl``` and clicking your wanted widgets

Comment: You can also click on the tree at right and click on the first widget, press ```shift``` and click to the last widget.

Comment: In this example, the widgets I want to select do not have consecutive index. And in other case, the index may be very random.

Comment: To select with mouse, select by pressing the scroll wheels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select multiple widgets by selecting a rectangle area with your mouse !
Not with the `left click`, but with `scroll wheels click`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Just try and select them with CTRL+Click.
If you can't do that check if the objects are locked in place.

Also you should be able to access your widgets through the side panel on the left (see fig.1)

[image: fig.1]

As I said earlier I can't 100% identify your problem remotely - I have no problems in a new fresh project.
I am using Qt Creator 4.10 (Community Edition)

[image: fig.2]

You could also check whether your file is even writable, just look in the upper left corner of the Designer and check whether the lock is closed or open. (See fig. 3)

[image: fig.3]

Comment: Is there any way more simple than this? Sometimes I may want select many widgets. Clicking one by one seems time consuming.

Comment: I tried to recreate your project and had no Problem whatsoever selecting all widgets with my rectangle mouse area.
I would recommend you check your widgets status to make sure they aren't locked, and in front.
Normally a invisible widget would cause a weird problem like that.

Comment: Would you tell me how to do that? Thanks. After I pressed left mouse, the QStackedWidget will be selected, and then when I move my mouse the whole QStackedWidget will be moved.

Comment: Please check my edit - I can't think of any other possibilities right now - perhaps create a new project and recreate your ui - do you have the same issues?